# why delphi source code is comparing single like comparing integer?

Tags: delphi

I discover in the delphi source code many code like this one :

```
procedure TControl.SetOpacity(const Value: Single);
begin
  if FOpacity <> Value then
  begin
    FOpacity := Value;
    if FOpacity < 0 then
      FOpacity := 0;
    if FOpacity > 1 then
      FOpacity := 1;
    RecalcOpacity;
    Repaint;
  end;
end;
```

I think (except for 0) that `FOpacity <> Value` will always return true. So what the purpose to do this comparaison ?

Comment: What makes you think that `FOpacity` is always `0` when you enter this method? Or are you thinking that comparing floating-point values using the equality operator `=` is always wrong? If `x` is a floating point variable, then `x = y` will be `true` if they are identical, even if `x` isn't `0`. It *is* true that you often want to take floating-point/numerical fuzz into account and use epsilons, `SameValue` and stuff, but in this case it makes perfect sense to compare the two floating-point values strictly.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: if you compare Two floating-point values strictly then FOpacity <> Value will always return true and then you will always call RecalcOpacity and  Repaint even if not need :(

Comment: No, that is simply not true. Try the following Delphi code: `var
  a, b: double;
begin
  a := pi;
  b := pi;
  if a <> b then
    ShowMessage('not equal');` Of course, an epsilon-based test (like `not SameValue(a, b)`)  will be `false` in *more* instances, and in many cases this would be an improvement, but the simple `=` test is still much better than no test at all.

Comment: [For a less trivial case, try `a := pi/4;
  b := arctan(1);`. Still equal on my machine/compiler.]

Comment: "FOpacity <> Value will always return true". This is wrong. Hence the entire question makes no sense.

Comment: @rudy Neither Value nor FOpacity are constants.

Comment: Hmmm... Ok, but the value assigned remains constant, i.e. it is never processed (converted, calculated), it will not change and can easily be compared to another value of the same type.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Unchanged or unmodified would be a better phrase to use because "constant" has a very specific meaning

Comment: @David: yes, that would probably be better.

Answer (score 3):

I misunderstood the question to be why there is a comparison at all, while the question actually asks why a direct comparison is used instead of one via `SameValue()` which one would usually use to compare floating point values.

I leave the answer here because it is not false (just answers a different question) and might help people stumbling over this page.

---

This is so that setting a property to the value it already has will not trigger activities that only need to happen when the property is assigned a new value.

In this example, there is no need to redraw the control if the value of the opacity property doesn't change.

```
myControl.Opacity := 0.5;

[...]

// some time later, should not trigger repaint of control, because nothing changes
myControl.Opacity := 0.5;
```

Comment: In *theory*, you are correct - absolutely that the purpose of the construct is to prevent needless processing. The problem with using floating-point is a different issue - one which EMBT refuses to acknowledge or fix. In Delphi, comparisons against a literal constant are always made against the constant as an *extended* value, whereas (as in this case) the variable being tested may be stored as some other precision. In the specific cases mentioned, `0`, `1` and `0.5`, this is likely to be of little matter - but in the case of `pi` or `e`, it's very significant.

Comment: @Magoo You are wide of the mark here, imagining problems where none exist. At the point of the comparison we have two single values. That's all that matters.